# how can i link a page for admin and staff with separate pages

Tags: php, html, sql, database, phpmyadmin

How can i add a line that when everytime i login for admin account ill be redirected to the admin page then if im a staff ill be redirected to the staff page? I just put the @$roles=$_POST['admin']; since it has a value in the database like admin and staff.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['login']))
  {
    @$username=$_POST['username'];
    @$password=$_POST['password'];
    @$roles=$_POST['admin'];
    @$roles=$_POST['staff'];
    $query = "select * from userinfotbl where username='$username' and password='$password' ";
    //echo $query;
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);
    if($query_run)
    {
      if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
      {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

      header( "Location: index.php");
      }
      else
      {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("No such User exists. Invalid Credentials")</script>';
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Database Error")</script>';
    }
  }
  else
  {
  }
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a column that tells what kind of account it is?

Comment: General reminder, don't use `@` to cover up errors, check if the variables are set instead.

Comment: @Swellar there is, the field name is roles or $roles, under that there are the values of admin and staff

Comment: You are also overriding the value of `$roles` ! `@$roles=$_POST['admin'];
    @$roles=$_POST['staff'];`

Comment: Just to be clear, I am asking about the database and not the inputs that you have since based from your code, you are getting the roles from the form, rather than to the database. Anyway, since you said you have a column `roles`, after validating the credentials, get the value of `roles` for that account, then it is just a matter of `if/else` statement

Comment: What are you passing in $_POST['admin'] and $_POST['staff'] ??

Answer (score 0):

1)pick roles of the user from DB based on user id.

2)check if the role chosen by him is allowed to him or not.

3)if(in_array($role,$roleAllowed)

```
   {
     switch($role)
     {
        case 'admin' :
         header( "Location: index1.php");
         break;
        case  'user' :
          header( "Location: index2.php");
          break;
      }
 }
```

Comment: keeping unencrypted password in session is not a great idea.